# Building With Mono element with the same key already exists with Generic.Dictionary

Tags: c#, mono

I am building an application in mono that builds and runs in visual studios with out any issue. However, the code base is somewhat large(with different assemblies) . I don't understand why mono is outputting the following 2 errors ? This shows up in 2 projects in the solution (the error is the exact same, except that MY_PROJECT is the name of the failing project)

```
/usr/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.targets: Error: Tool exited with code: 1. Output: Mono License Compiler
Copyright (c) 2009 by RemObjects Software
Exception: System.ArgumentException: An element with the same key already exists in the dictionary.
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Reflection.Assembly].Add (System.String key, System.Reflection.Assembly value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at LC.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
 (MY_PROJECT)
```

Comment: My mono version:
mono JIT compiler version 3.2.8 (tarball Mon Mar  3 12:37:20 UTC 2014)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  amd64
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug 
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            sgen

Comment: As it's a dictionary of assemblies, that suggests that you have two libraries with the same name.